# Prepositions with "to reflect"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

When to use "on" or "in" with the verb "reflect" when referring to a mirrored image? Eg. "The moon was reflected ON/IN the sea.

Comment: We normally use 'in' when referring to a reflection in a mirror or equivalent. You might say 'reflected on the surface of the sea'.

Comment: @Kate's (first) suggestion is supported by the data shown in [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=moon+was+reflected+in+the%2Cmoon+was+reflected+on+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmoon%20was%20reflected%20in%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmoon%20was%20reflected%20on%20the%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: What about in mathematics, where an object is reflected on/at/across/about a plane?

Answer (score 0):

The sea, or water is generally considered a surface.
So **on** should be your answer.

Comment: If the sea or water is the reflecting surface, then it's 'in'. If an image is projected, and that image appears on the surface, like a wall, then it's 'on' or 'onto'.

Answer (score 0):

According to TheFreeDictionary, **reflected on** is defined as:

> Literally, to be displayed as a duplicate light or image on something.
>
> > *Technically, moonlight is just sunlight that bounces off the moon and
> >     is reflected on the Earth.*
> >
> > *Though his back was to me, I could see his
> >     worried face reflected on the small pool of water.*

In the meanwhile, **reflected in** means:

> Literally, shown as a duplicate image on a reflective surface.
>
> > *The mountain was perfectly reflected in the crystal-clear lake.*
> >
> > *The entire street was reflected in the office building's mirror-like windows.*

There doesn't seem to be much of a difference between the two, if the examples and definitions are anything to go by. The lack of any difference between the two is also evident in a few examples featured in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reflect), where the two are seemingly used interchangeably:

> *He saw himself reflected in the water/mirror/shop window.*
>
> *The candlelight reflected on his gold wristwatch.*

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reflected%20in%2Creflected%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creflected%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creflected%20on%3B%2Cc0) suggests that **reflected in** is much more popular than **reflected on**, so I'd recommend following the trend and use the former if you want to describe an image that's projected on a surface.